# Hiding apex:output field

Tags: visualforce

I'm writing a visualforce  page and i want to hide `<apex:outputfield>` tag label in visualforce page.
Need help to achieve this- 
and  If I want to show custom labels to this field how can I achieve the same ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you include an `<apex:outputField>` or an `<apex:inputField>` component in an `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`, these components do not display with their label or custom help text as they do when they are children of an `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>`.

Also note that `<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>` components cannot be **rerendered;**  rerender the child components instead.
If you want to hide `<apex:outputField>` values label in visualforce page, you can use either above mentioned note or you can go through following strategy.

Just include your `<apex:outputField>`  tags in  `<apex:panelGrid>` tag which will hide the field labels.

If you want to display labels of `<apex:outputField>`  values , simply remove `<apex:panelGrid>` tag, or you can use `<apex:outputLabel>` tag. Using  “apex:outputLabel” tag you can give custom label to respective  values.

To show default Labels of `<apex:outputField>` values on the Visualforce pages simply put all the `<apex:outputField>` tags in `<apex:pageblocksection>` tag.